# Yii2 Expression dose not work

Tags: php, yii2

I have two models classes (tables) and I have not any FK between the two tables

table1 : ['id', 'name' ]
table2 : ['id', 'status' , 'controller']

the table2 is a generic table that can be related dynamicaly with many other tables, so there any FK

in the model class of the table1 I want to write the getTable2 methode that get all records in table2 with a static controller name

my code

```
use yii\db\Expression;
.....

public function getTable2s()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Table2::className(), ['controller' => new Expression('table1-controller')]);
    }
```

I want that the request take the 'table1-controller' as a string value but my problem is that I have an error

Undefined column: 7 ERREUR:  the column table1.table1-controller dose not exist

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. verify your  DB schema. Probably there is a mistake in the field/attribute naming or i the mapping in the function.

Comment: there are no error in de DB schema , there are more thant 10 modules that use this schema

Answer (score 0):

You can find table2 items with:

```
$table2Objects = Table2::find()->where(['controller' => 'table1-controller')])->all();
```

But I wouldn't create a method getTable2s in the table1 class if it has nothing to do with table2 class. Alternatively, you could add a static method to the table2 class:

```
public static function findEntries($controller) {
    return self::find()->where(['controller' => $controller])->all();
}
```